# Recurse operating on file-less folders - need to only work on folder that contain files

Tags: powershell, scripting, windows-scripting

I am working on a PowerShell script to archive old logs. The goal is to take the logs older than X days from all our other scripts, events, software, etc, (which are logged to a central log store) and zip them up for long term storage. The script works great when there is only one level of nested folders, which contain files. The problem is that it doesn't work well when there are two (or more) layers of nested folders.

Here's an example of the folder structure at the central log store:

```
\\store
└─logs
  ├─ops
  │ ├─ScriptAlpha
  │ │ ├─ScriptA-2018-10-17.log
  │ │ └─ScriptA-2018-10-10.log
  │ └─ScriptBeta
  │   ├─ScriptB-2018-11-17.log
  │   └─ScriptB-2018-11-09.log
  ├─Maintenance
  │ └─ScriptA
  │   ├─ScriptA-2018-10-22.log
  │   └─ScriptA-2018-10-26.log
  └─Ondemand
    └─ScriptBigly
      └─ScriptB-2018-11-27.log
```

I have another set of logs that I built a script to zip up, and it works great, but only when there are no multiply nested folders. The target for that one looks like this:

```
\\store2
└─Output
  ├─Alpha
  │ └─Alpha-2018-11-27.log
  ├─Bravo
  │ ├─Alpha-2018-11-27.log
  │ └─Alpha-2018-11-19.log
  ├─Charlie
  │ ├─Alpha-2018-11-27.log
  │ ├─Alpha-2018-11-18.log
  │ └─Alpha-2018-11-04.log
  └─Delta
    └─Alpha-2018-11-27.log
```

On the second directory, I execute the script against \\store2\output with `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` and it works great! However, as soon as I try to do the same script against \\store\logs  it does things I don't want it to. I think maybe I don't know how to use `-Recurse` appropriately.

The first thing I do with the script is create PSDrives for the root folder of the logs (e.g., `$sourcedrive = New-PSdrive -Name E -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\\store\logs`

Then I kick off a loop to iterate through and zip the contents. Here's the `Foreach` loop, but there are some functions I define elsewhere. If I need to include those, just let me know and I'll add them, but it's quite a long script with them included (401 lines in total).

```
$Targets = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $SourceDrive | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }).FullName
Write-Host "kicking off the foreach loop"
foreach ($Dir in $Targets) {
    Write-Host "Looking for relevant files"
    $Files = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $Dir -Exclude *.7z, *.zip | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-$Days)})
    Write-Host "$($Files.count) files older than $Days days found in $Dir" -ForegroundColor Green
    if ($files.Count -gt 0) {
        Write-Host "Compressing files in $dir" 
        Compress-Files $Files       #Moves the files into a working folder, then zips that folder
        Write-Host "Checking if zip created succesfully"
        if ($fileszipped = $true) {
            #Now that the files are all zipped, we can remove the source files, or not
            if ($nomove.IsPresent ) {
                Write-Host "Zip created! Removing working directories from $Dir and clearing out old files, not moving zip"
                Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $sourcedrive | Where-Object {
                    $_.PSIsContainer -and ($_.BaseName -like '*WorkingFiles*')
                } | Remove-Item -Recurse -Verbose
            } else {
                #If we didn't specify -nomove, then we can copy the zips, then remove the source files
                Write-Host "Zip created! Copying zip files now"
                $destin = (Join-Path -Path $LTSdrive -ChildPath (Split-Path $dir -Leaf))
                $ExitCode = Start-Robocopy -source $Dir -destin $destin -Verbose
                #Assuming robocopy was successful, let's remove our working directory and the files we've just zipped
                Write-Host "Checking if zip(s) copied succesfully"
                if (ParseRobocopyOutput $ExitCode){
                    Write-Host "Zip(s) copied! Removing working directories from $Dir and clearing out old files"
                    Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $sourcedrive | Where-Object {
                        $_.PSIsContainer -and ($_.BaseName -like '*WorkingFiles*')
                    } | Remove-Item -Recurse -Verbose
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For reference, here is the "actual" part of the `Compress-Files` function:

```
$Path0 = $Path +"\WorkingFiles"
if ($Check -eq $false) {
    New-Item -Path $Path -ItemType Directory -Name WorkingFiles -Verbose
}

$i = 0
while ($i -lt $Files.Count) {
    $Path1 = $Path +"\"+ $Files[$i]
    Move-Item -Path $Path1 -Destination $Path0 -Verbose
    $i++
}
```

When I kick this off, it operates as I want it to on the \\store2\Output folders. But when I kick it off against \\store\logs, it tries to move everything in \ops\scriptAlpha AND everything in \ops\scriptBeta into a zip file in \ops which doesn't suit the need. What I am looking to have at the end is:

```
\\Archive
├─ops
│ ├─ScriptAlpha
│ │ └─ScriptA-archive-2018-11.7z
│ └─ScriptBeta
│   └─ScriptB-archive-2018-11.7z
├─Maintenance
│ ├─ScriptA
│ │ └─ScriptA-archive-2018-11.7z
│ └─ScriptBigly
│   └─ScriptB-archive-2018-11.7z
└─Output
  ├─Alpha
  │ └─Alpha-archive-2018-11.7z
  ├─Bravo
  │ └─Alpha-archive-2018-11.7z
  └─Charlie
    └─Alpha-archive-2018-11.7z
```

Instead, what I'm getting is a zip that contains all ScriptAlpha (and its folders/files) and all ScriptBeta (and its folders/files) information in a WorkingFolder at the \ops level which gets zipped up all together.

What I was thinking I might do instead is go through the root and feed each directory into an array, then operate on each item in the array to see if it has files in it, and if it has files in it, then do the compress-files. However, I don't know if that would do it or not. I'm kind of stuck, mentally.

I appreciate the help! And for what it's worth, I've googled and searched SO and I can't really find anything.

Comment: Have your code process `\\store\logs\*` instead of `\\store\logs`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Two things: First off, THANK YOU for the amazing work on the formatting! How'd you do the thing with the folder structures, that's beautiful! And I'd like to have that for the next time I have a question.

Second, Would doing that (using the *) work for iterating through each subfolder? I mean, if there are additional levels? The folder at Ops doesn't contain any files, just folders. And I think there may be an additional layer of folders under Ops in one of the subfolders. Would simply adding the * account for that as well?

Comment: If there are additional directory levels you need to provide a more representative sample of your source data structure and the desired end result (from that sample).